# Too many open files Maven Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, build, build-process

I've come across an error which I cannot figure out, even after extensive internet searching.

I am running a Maven project in Java to SSH to a remote location, the project had been building fine for the past week until I encountered this error message:

> Error executing Maven.
>   2 problems were encountered while building the effective settings
>   Non-readable settings /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/conf/settings.xml: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/conf/settings.xml (Too many open files in system) @ /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/conf/settings.xml
>   Failed to use environment variables for interpolation: Cannot run program "env": error=23, Too many open files in system @

Is there a way to delete these *files* as I cannot build my application anymore.

Many thanks

David

Comment: Is maven running in the remote location? What OS are you using in the remote location? If it is *NIX, perhaps you could run these commands to find out the allowed max number of open files: `ulimit -aS` and `ulimit -aH`

Comment: I'm running maven on my local machine as a Maven project with Java, would you be able to explain further how I can run these commands?

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ulimit -v unlimited in the bash profile of user.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and feedback the outcome

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn clean`
This removes all files generated by the previous build.